# Unable to use USB after minor kernel upgrade

Tags: usb, 16.04, kernel

Ubuntu 16.04.1 works fine with the supplied (`4.4.0-21-generic`) kernel. When I upgrade to `4.4.0-22-generic` using `apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0.22-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic` and restart with the new kernel, my USB keyboard stops working after the grub screen, and it looks like networking fails too, but it's hard to diagnose at the Emergency Mode prompt without a functioning keyboard.

If I use grub to boot the 4.4.0-21-generic kernel, the keyboard works fine, but I really need that new kernel to work to solve [another problem I'm having](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1557776).

Answer (score 3):

Just for others having the same problem (I had it too) - solution is described here - https://blog.al4.co.nz/2014/12/ubuntu-14-04-no-usb-keyboard-after-upgrading-kernel/
You need to boot to older kernel, and check if you have installed "linux-image-extra-x.x.x-xx-generic" package for your latest kernel.